# R: MICE and backwards stepwise regression

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, logistic-regression, r-mice

I've imputed my data using the following code:

`data_imp <- mice(data, m=5, maxit=50, meth='pmm', seed=500, printFlag=FALSE)`

`data.impute <- complete(data_imp, action = 1)`

I wanted to perform backwards stepwise regression using the stepAIC function in order to find the most parsimonious model. How can I do this using all 5 of my imputed datasets, rather than just 1?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to apply it to each dataset separately; see below for some example code.

However, let me also give you two MASSIVE disclaimers here:

1. Backwards stepwise regression is really really not recommended for variable selection. In addition, there are better ways to do this for imputed datasets.
2. From the code below, you would still have to decide on HOW to pool your results into one interpretable set. One way would be to simply count how often each variable ends up in the final model. However, this procedure implicitly carries a loss of information.

A more extensive discussion of these points can be found here:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110585/stepwise-regression-modeling-using-multiply-imputed-data-sets

The author of `mice` also has a subchapter on variable selection in his book:
https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-stepwise.html

I would thus consider whether there are better options out there for you.

**Example code**

```r
## I am using `mtcars`
## Let's ampute it, then impute it
data_imp <- mice(ampute(mtcars, prop = 0.001)$amp)

## Next, we loop over all imputed datasets
out <- lapply(seq_len(data_imp$m), function(i) {

  ## We create a dataset
  data.i <- complete(data_imp, i)

  ## We run our model
  fit <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = data.i)

  ## We apply `stepAIC`
  stepAIC(fit, trace = FALSE)
})
```